# Dynamic Programming for test tube

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Eli is a teenager who loves to study chemistry. She recently joined a chemistry research lab.

Dr. Phil wants her to just play around with some chemicals and observe their reaction.

Therefore, he gave her a one-row tray of test tubes with the different chemical inside of them
and told her:

"Mix these chemical together anyhow that you like, but the you have to follow two rules:

1. Never make a mixture that has two chemicals that their tubes are next to each other.
2. Keep adding more chemical to the mixture until it is not violating the new rule."

For example, in the image you can see she was given 5 tubes and she is able to make 4 different mixture without violating the rule: {1,3,5}, {2,4}, {2,5}, {1,4}.

But she cannot mix 1 and 3 only because she still can
add 5 without violating the rules.

She is curious to know how many different mixtures
she can make without violating the rule with any
given number of tubes.

That's why she asks you
write a code to calculate it for her.

Input

The input will consist of a sequence of numbers N, 1 ≤ N ≤ 76. Each number will be on a
separate line.

The input will be terminated by 0.

Output

Output the number of different mixture she can make without violating the rule mentioned
above on a single line as show in the sample. The number of all subsets will be less than 2^31

Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Output:

```
0
0
1
3
4
5
7
9
```

Is it possible for me to use the formula like Mix[i] = Mix[i - 2] + Mix[i - 3] to find the answer, because I notice a pattern, so I tried using this formula, but can't quite the answer for input 4,5 and 6

Comment: https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/15834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close to the answer. Let's define an array called `dp` where `dp[i]` is the number of ways to mix `i` chemicals **always including the `i`th chemical in the mixure**. To compute `dp[i]`, we have two cases:

1. Include the `i - 2`th chemical, with `dp[i - 2]` possible ways.
2. Include the `i - 3`th chemical but not the `i - 2`th chemical, with `dp[i - 3]` possible ways.

We must either include the `i - 2`th chemical or the `i - 3`th chemical because if we don't include one of them, it would be possible to include the `i - 2`th chemical which violates the rule.

So `dp[i] = dp[i - 2] + dp[i - 3]`, which matches your formula. However, this is not the solution (yet). Remember that `dp[i]` only counts the number of possible mixtures including the `i`th chemical. We need to add to that the number of possible mixtures not including the `i`th chemical, which is simply `dp[i - 1]`. Therefore, our answer is `dp[i] + dp[i - 1]`.

For some implementation details, we have to hardcode `dp[0]`, `dp[1]`, and `dp[2]` as our base cases. Also, we need to hardcode the output for inputs 1 to 3 because for those inputs it's possible to have a "mixture" consisting of a single chemical which isn't valid.

Comment: so it means that dp[i]=dp[i]+dp[i-1]?

Comment: @MuhdIqbal `dp[i] = dp[i - 2] + dp[i - 3]`, but that's not the answer. The answer for `i` chemicals is `dp[i] + dp[i - 1]`.

Comment: So sorry, I still can't quite get it, can you show work step for getting output for input 4,5,6 thank you very much in advance , really appreciate it if you can do it, sorry for being ignorant

Comment: @MuhdIqbal The `dp` array will end up looking like this (starting from index 0): `0 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5 7 9 12...` The answer for 4 is `dp[4] + dp[3]`, which is `2 + 1 = 3`. The answer for 5 is `dp[5] + dp[4] = 2 + 2 = 4`. 6 is `dp[6] + dp[5] = 3 + 2 = 5`. Remember that the `dp` array doesn't store the answer. `dp[i]` stores the number of mixtures that includes the `i`th chemical. Also, this algorithm counts mixtures with a single chemical for inputs 1 to 3 which aren't valid in the problem, so you have to hardcode the output for inputs 1 to 3.

Comment: @MuhdIqbal If my answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it by clicking the outline of a checkmark below the upvote and downvote arrows. It helps me a lot and it marks the question as answered. You're not required to do this though.

Comment: I forgot one more thing, how did you figure this out, is there a number theory or algorithm for solving this question? Would really love to know

Comment: @MuhdIqbal It's mostly just experience dealing with problems like these. I quickly figured it can be solved with a DP, and the states and transitions are relatively easy.

Comment: Wow, you're awesome, glad you helped ne